# What does $||$ operator mean?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

I'm trying to implement color to grayscale method from this paper:
http://www.cs.kent.edu/~zhao/papers/SpectralDecolor.pdf

And I'm not really sure what does mean this operator $||$ from this equatation:

$\theta=\frac{|\hat{R}|+|\hat{G}|+|\hat{B}|-|\hat{L}|}{|\hat{R}|+|\hat{G}|+|\hat{B}|}$

In paper it states $||$ represents the spectrum of the complex values, $\hat{R},\hat{G},\hat{B}$
are Fourier transform
results of R, G, B channels. $\hat{L}$ is Fourier transform result of luminance.

Given computed coefficients by Fourier transform are complex numbers. I guess the operator could be defined as $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ or $|z|=a^2+b^2$, where $z=a+b\mathrm{i}$. But I'm not really sure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure their statement that it is the "spectrum of a complex values" is a mistake and your first interpretation is right,  i. e. the one with the square root

Comment: Have you seen the [Digital Signal Processing StackExchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: No I have't, Thanks for the notice. I would ask further questions regarding color to grayscale conversion there.